# How do I add a controller (MVC) to my JavaFX application which I wrote in Java?

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx, connector

So I created an app containing the following classes: Main.java (where launch is along with window, scenes, buttons, etc.), Students.java (students), Connection.java (JDBC connects to MySQL database). There's also a class for login (with its own window, scenes, buttons), a class for charts (opens up a Pie Chart) as well as a confirmbox and alertbox (again with windows, scenes and buttons)...

I then read that good practice is to use MVC by looking through different tutorials plus previous answers here. Additionally the best tutorial was this: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/

The problem with this tutorial however was that it uses scene builder... I wish to create my application by writing code instead. And with my existing code (I can run the app on my IDE and buttons etc. work perfectly, fetches data from database too...) but what do I do with connector?

Do I create a new one?

(NOTE: all my classes are in .src)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A javafx controller is used to control  UI elements. One way to attach controller is by adding **fx:controller="controllerClassLocation"** in your fxml file.

Another way would be to add controller in your code but this also involves fxml file as shown below.

```
      String fxmlPath="MainLayout.fxml";                               
      private Scene getScene(String fxmlPath, ControllerClass controller) {
        FXMLLoader loader;
        Parent parent;
        Scene scene;
        try {
            //not FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath)
            loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
            loader.setController(controller);
            parent = loader.load();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        scene = new Scene(parent);

        return scene;

    }
```

You use a controller if you want to bind your javafx UI elements.

If you do not want to use fxml file then you will have to code all the UI elements and bind to their respective functions and events for controlling them. For eg: In the below example a **button btn** is created and an event is handled when the button is clicked. The Button btn is binded to the function s**etOnAction(new EventHandler())** .

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote below is what I have in my own program. Noob question: is this sufficient? or do I need to create a separate class called controller? Also, is it good practice? (Sorry am new to MVC and just read about it...)

Comment: You dont have to write your own controller if you don't want to use fxml files but you will have to call respective functions that trigger the particular UI element. 
You should practice writing fxml files and (ofcourse controllers) as it will reduce the burden of writing code (and will save lots and lots of time). You should definitely learn scenebuilder and it's not hard. 
Anything that is neat and clean and saves good amount of time without degrading performance is a good practice and that is why you should learn about implementing your own controllers.

Comment: It's not compulsory to create own controller class but you should create your own controller class otherwise you will produce a mess that will be hard to read.

Comment: So in the example above I would have a button btn... Then I have to create a new class (in the same package, also something I am confused about) and then I write "btn.setOnAction..." etc? Could you illustrate that for me? xD

Comment: You would create a button and add the btn.setOnAction.. feature in the controller class. Let's say when a user clicks on that button a different window pops up. Now that different will have its own controller and (of course its own set of UI elements).  
Please refer to caveofprogramming.com for basic tutorial and after that go to youtube and search for the string "Almas javafx". He has some solid tutorials. Here is his github page: github.com/AlmasB/FXTutorials/tree/master/src/com/almasb.

You will learn a lot if you follow them step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller class just like you would using FXML. Create an instance of the controller and pass on all references of your controls that you created in the code where you create all the controls.

Doing this way, you cannot leverage the benefits of FXML binding, such as fx:id, fx:controller and event bindings.